# jQuery Object value by Name

Tags: jquery

I have used Jquery for some time now but run in to a problem today which I have tried all sorts to resolve.

I am searching for some html elements using the name. for example I obtain a form from the DOM with `var form = $(formId);` the formId looks like this '#Guid-document-form', this works ok I get the form object.

I then query the form object for the value of a textarea with the below snippet,

```
var docCommentQuery = 'textarea[name="Files\\[' + arrayId + '\\]\\.Comment"]';
```

arrayId is in int which is passed to the function performing the query so have to build up the selector as above.

I then use `var docCommentVal = $(form).find(docCommentQuery).val();` to try and obtain the value of the textarea but the value returned is always undefined. I have tried all kinds of things but no joy.

I have read the jquery documentation and the WC3 standard and both say to escape meta characters, which is what I am doing above.

Has anyone any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, take the slashes out of `docCommentQuery` - they *shouldn't* be escaped - they're part of the selector.

Comment: `'textarea[name="Files[' + arrayId + '].Comment"]'` or `'textarea[name=Files\\[' + arrayId + '\\]\\.Comment]'` but not `'textarea[name="Files\\[' + arrayId + '\\]\\.Comment"]'`

Comment: can you add the markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, you escape meta characters that you need to be treated as the literal characters, **unless** they're part of the value in an attribute selector *contained within double quotes*.

Since the second set of `[]` and the `.` after are part of the value for the name attribute, you don't need to escape them:

```
textarea[name="Files[' + arrayId + '].Comment"]
```

If, however, you wanted to compare the value of an attribute called name[] (rather than just name), you would need to escape the `[]` pair that's part of the attribute name (but not the ones that are part of the attribute value):

```
textarea[name\\[\\]="Files[' + arrayId + '].Comment"]
```

Comment: Hay thanks for the explanation that has helped out allot.

Answer (score 0):

```
var files="Files[' + arrayId + ']";
var docCommentQuery = 'textarea[name="+files+.Comment"]';
```

Can you try above code once.Hope it may help